# check50 on plurality insists that it doesn't work yet everytime i try with my own input it does work

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

The program in question gets candidate names and voters choices as input and the output is the name of the winner or winners(in case there is a tie between 2 or mre candidates).
whenever I try using my own input it works fine, be it a single winner or multiple.
yet check50 disagrees. when I use the debugger it says in the end something about segmentation fault but I can't see where in the code is the error.

I'm having a problem understanding why check50 insists the program isn't fully correct.
The part of the code which the problem is in is:

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int c = 0;
    int d[(candidate_count - 1)];
    int e = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[c].votes < candidates[i].votes)
        {
            c = i;
        }
        else if (candidates[c].votes == candidates[i].votes)
        {
            d[e] = i;
            e++;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", candidates[c].name);
    for(int i = 0; i < (e + 1); i++)
    {
        if(candidates[c].votes == candidates[(d[i])].votes)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[d[i]].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

the results are:

```
:) plurality.c exists
:) plurality compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of first candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of middle candidate
:) vote returns true when given name of last candidate
:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
:) vote produces correct counts when all votes are zero
:) vote produces correct counts after some have already voted
:) vote leaves vote counts unchanged when voting for invalid candidate
:) print_winner identifies Alice as winner of election
:) print_winner identifies Bob as winner of election
:) print_winner identifies Charlie as winner of election
:) print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie
:( print_winner prints all names when all candidates are tied
    print_winner function did not print all three winners of election
```

Comment: Not sure, but this: `for(int i = 0; i < (e + 1); i++)` looks strange. I would expect  `i < e`

Comment: Welcome to SO. A segmentation fault is clearly some situation that is not considered a PASS. Normally check50 provides some information about the test data. At least for other tasks. What extra information does it show for that failed test case?

Comment: What is the purpose of an array that can hold `candidate_count - 1` entries? What is the ranges for `i` in your loops?

Comment: Edit the question to contain a [mre]. If you do not have sample input that reproduces the problem, you can leave that out, but at least provide a complete program that others can compile and execute.

Answer (score 0):

From:

```
            d[e] = i;
            e++;
```

we see that `e` is one greater than the index of the last element set in `d`.

Then:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < (e + 1); i++)
    {
        if(candidates[c].votes == candidates[(d[i])].votes)
```

executes an iteration in which `i` is `e` and so `d[i]` is `d[e]`, which accesses an element beyond the last element set in `d`. This value is uninitialized and may behave as if it has a very large positive or negative value (thus causing a segment fault as the expression tries to access memory out of bounds) or a small value that results in accessing some unwanted element in `candidates` (thus printing an incorrect name), or it may have some other undesired behavior in your program.

Change the `for` statement to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++)
```

Answer (score -1):

Segmentation fault happens when the program tries to access an invalid memory address, e.g. if you try to access `a[10]` of a vector `int a[10]`. Note that indexing in C is zero-based, which means `10` is the 11th element. And it is happening in some parts of your code:

```c
int d[candidate_count - 1];
...
for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    if (candidates[c].votes < candidates[i].votes)
    ...
```

When `i = candidate_count - 1` in last iteration, the index `i` is out of the limits of the vector which is has size `candidate_count-1`. You can try something like:

```c
int d[candidate_count];
...
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    if (candidates[c].votes < candidates[i].votes)
    ...
```

See this [Wikipedia article about segfault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

Comment: The statements you show access `candidates`, which presumably has at least `candidate_count` elements. They do not access `d`, which has only `candidate_count - 1` elements, and therefore this is not the source of the problem. The statement in that first loop that does access `d`, using `d[e]`, is executed with a maximum value of `e` of `candidate_count - 2`, so it is not the source of the problem either. (`e` may reach a value of `candidate_count - 1`, but only in the `e++` that follows `d[e] = i;` in the last iteration.)